# Postgres crosstab query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has 7 different classes with an area value.

```
pid | class| area | 
----+------+------+
2   | 1    | 10   | 
2   | 2    | 10   | 
2   | 6    | 20   | 
4   | 1    | 30   | 
4   | 2    | 40   | 
4   | 3    | 50   | 
4   | 4    | 60   | 
4   | 5    | 70   | 
9   | 6    | 80   | 
11  | 1    | 90   | 
11  | 4    | 10   | 
11  | 7    | 20   |
```

However I want to present this data in a format that has each distinct `pid` as a column heading and then have each row correspond to a class area (i.e. first row is the area of class 1 for each `pid`).

```
2  |  4  |  9  | 11 |
---+-----+-----+----+
10 |  30 |  0  | 90 |
10 |  40 |  0  |  0 |
0  |  50 |  0  |  0 |
0  |  60 |  0  | 10 |    
0  |  70 |  0  |  0 |
20 |   0 |  60 |  0 |
0  |   0 |  0  | 20 |
```

Is it possible to create an output like this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN pid = 2 THEN area ELSE 0 END) As "2",
    SUM(CASE WHEN pid = 4 THEN area ELSE 0 END) As "4",
    SUM(CASE WHEN pid = 9 THEN area ELSE 0 END) As "9",
    SUM(CASE WHEN pid = 11 THEN area ELSE 0 END) As "11"
FROM t
GROUP BY class
ORDER BY class
```